# SQL Relation Error

Tags: sql, sql-server

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть таблица с пользователями (где их credentials), есть с инфой о пользователях.
Нужно, чтобы поля Email и UserName для них были общими, т.е. зеркальными.
Пытаюсь соединить Id первого и Id второго, правило линкования - каскад.
После чего получаю такую вот ошибку((
Как можно линковать по другому?

Comment: У Вас типы столбцов разные.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У Вас тип данных `Id` разный(`navchar` и `int`), должны быть одинаковые

Comment: Спасибо большое, заработался.
У меня ещё один вопрос, если не будет сложно: типы поставил одинаковые и соединил, но после линковки во второй таблице инстансы из первой не появились. Просто пустые места.
Как получить референс? Наверное надо запустить какой-нибудь refresh, или что-то в этом роде?

Comment: Они не будут дублироваться, более того, Вам не требуется дублировать колонки(Если это не является необходимым требованием системы). Для получения скажем email из второй таблицы, при запросе, Вам нужно использовать JOIN и данные из второй таблицы добавятся к первой в ответе.

Comment: Нет, конечно же не дублировать, мне нужно именно отражение, т.е. что-то вроде ссылки на первую таблицу.
Я, к сожалению, не могу пользоваться стандартными SQL запросами, т.к. все должно быть сделано через Entity Framework.
Не знаю, возможно ли сделать зеркальный reference или нет, но я точно помню, что когда-то видел такое на MS Access, поэтому спрашиваю.

Comment: Уверен, что в нём есть метод join() или подобный. Попробуйте поискать информацию о том, как использовать join в этом фреймворке, я к сожалению не могу Вам с ним помочь.